# cc1plus.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to run a c++ program on windows 10

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

when I try to run g++ hello.cpp

The procedure entry point libiconv could not be located in dynamic link library
C:\mingw\bin..\libexec\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\cc1plus.exe

I reinstalled MinGW but the error is the same.

[image: Error Screenshot]

[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: Please copy all relevant information into your question **as text**.

Comment: It appears you are trying to use `g++` in the CMD shell, rather than in the MSYS shell.  Does it work if you use the MSYS shell?

Comment: How do I run MSYS shell?

Comment: @gopal Quoting the MSYS wiki: "you should have a cyan "M" link on the Desktop. When you double-click on it, a terminal should be launched."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGW GCC 6.3.0 is really very old.
Try with a newer version like MinGW-w64 GCC 10.2.0 from http://winlibs.com/

The error *The procedure entry point libiconv could not be located* indicates there is an issue loading the libiconv DLL, possibly because it's loading the wrong DLL with the same name in a different location. I have seen this problem before if you have Oracle database (or client) installed.

Make sure the PATH environment variable lists the paths used by your application (including where your libiconv DLL file is located) before anything else.

I never recommend adding paths to the global `PATH` environment variable, so instead I recommend running this in your Command Prompt before building/running your application:

```
SET PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;<path_where_libiconv_dll_is>;$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Download other Compiler like Turbo or dev or Code:blocks or some kind of other editor and  try it returned. Its  because according to some entry point files are damaged else missed due to which it is causing the error

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to fix this specific error. is there any way I can fix those entry points?

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by following the steps

1. go to C:\Windows\SysWOW64
2. you will find a DLL file with the name `libiconv-2.dll`
3. rename the DLL file with anything_libiconv-2.dll and save
4. Try to run the C/C++ program it should work fine.

Comment: It's a bad idea to tamper with files under the Windows.
Probably that file got installed there by another application that you have now broken. A better solution is to set the `PATH` environment variable to list the paths used by your application (including where your `libiconv-2.dll` is) first. Something like this `SET PATH=C:\MinGW\bin;$PATH` in the Command Prompt